# How to get number of order in case mode

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query:

```
SELECT REPLACE(column1,'a','b') AS col ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN col like '%door%' THEN 1
WHEN col like '%window%' THEN 2
WHEN col like '%book%' THEN 3
ELSE 4
END
```

I want to know which row is in order number 1 and which row is in order number 2 and ...
how to find it?

Comment: Just run it - what's the issue?

Comment: @P.Salmon for example If row is in order number 3 or more, I should show to user a special message

Comment: but where's the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for get number of order in this example:

```
SELECT REPLACE(column1,'a','b') AS col, (CASE
    WHEN REPLACE(column1,'a','b') like '%door%' THEN 1
    WHEN REPLACE(column1,'a','b') like '%window%' THEN 2
    WHEN REPLACE(column1,'a','b') like '%book%' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END) AS ordr
FROM table ORDER BY ordr
```

Answer (score 1):

To your comment above, you could add a second `CASE` expression to the select clause:

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(column1,'a','b') AS col,
    CASE WHEN REPLACE(column1,'a','b') NOT LIKE '%door%' AND
              REPLACE(column1,'a','b') NOT LIKE '%window%'
         THEN 'special message' END AS msg
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN col like '%door%'   THEN 1
         WHEN col like '%window%' THEN 2
         WHEN col like '%book%'   THEN 3
         ELSE 4 END;
```